# Get return value of module in calling file

Tags: node.js, node-modules

my root node file requires a module called q1 (not including all the required libraries as not relevant)

```
const analyzeSentiment = function(message) {
    sentiment.getSentiment(message).then(result => {
        return (result.vote === 'positive') ? handlePositive() : handleNegative();
    });
}

const handlePositive = function() {
    return `That's great, we have an opening next Friday at 3pm. Would that work for you?`;
}

const handleNegative = function() {
    return `That's okay. Thanks for you time. If you change your mind, give us a call at (xxx) yyy-zzzz.`;
}

exports.analyzeSentiment = analyzeSentiment;
```

I call it like this: const message = require('q1').analyzeSentiment('text string');

With console logging I can see that it makes it down into the proper handlePositive or handleNegative methods, but nothing comes back. I've tried a few different ways but can't get it to work. Anyone have any suggestions, or see something blatantly wrong I'm doing? This is my first time working with node.

Comment: What is `sentimentAnalyzer`? it's not in the code? Also, if you want to return something from `analyzeSentiment` you need to return the whole statement `return sentiment.getSentiment(message).then(result => {
        return (result.vote === 'positive') ? handlePositive() : handleNegative();
    });`

Comment: That was me being an idiot and mispelling my own function call. It is correct in the code, just not here. Fixed. Thanks! And yeah, that is indeed what I was missing. Anonymous function wasn't returnned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `analyzeSentiment` not returning anything (see explanation further down).

Try this:

```
const analyzeSentiment = function(message) {
    return sentiment.getSentiment(message).then(result => {
        return (result.vote === 'positive') ? handlePositive() : handleNegative();
    });
}
```

And in your caller:

```
require('q1').sentimentAnalyzer('text string').then(message => {
    // Do your thing with the message here
});
```

Alternatively, if you are in an async context you can use await on the caller:

```
const message = await require('q1').sentimentAnalyzer('text string');
```

You might be wondering why the `return (result.vote === ...` isn't returning from your `analyzeSentiment`-function. The reason is that the you are creating an anonymous function with the arrow-expression `result => ...` in the `then`-block.